# Why is my website taking forever to load?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

https://nl.ipgmediabrands.com/

First thing you see on the frontpage. I am very sorry I can't be more specific. I do think it has something to do with my .htaccess file. Although WordPress says I fixed that problem, the website still won't load properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably something goes wrong with the settings of W3 Total Cache. Switch it off and see if it works. If it does not work all plugins once off and then turn on 1 for 1 again until it stops working you know in any case which plugin the problem is.

Comment: W3 Total Cache I will try, but I can't try switching of many others. As the website will get corrupted if I disable some of them. And as it is for work I can' take the risk.